# java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host

Tags: java, eclipse, исключения, rmi

При запуске *клиент-серверного* приложения, использующего механизм RMI, вылетает исключение `java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host`.

В самой программе используются четыре исходных файла:

**AddServerIntf.java**

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

interface AddServerIntf extends Remote {
    double add(double d1, double d2) throws RemoteException;
}
```

**AddServerImpl.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class AddServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements AddServerIntf {

    public AddServerImpl() throws RemoteException {
    }

    public double add(double d1, double d2) throws RemoteException {
        return d1 + d2;
    }
}
```

**AddServer.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;

public class AddServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            AddServerImpl addServerImpl = new AddServerImpl();
            Naming.rebind("AddServer", addServerImpl);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

**AddClient.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;

public class AddClient {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String addServerURL = "rmi://" + args[0] + "/AddServer";
            AddServerIntf addServerIntf = (AddServerIntf) Naming.lookup(addServerURL);
            System.out.println("The first number is: " + args[1]);
            double d1 = Double.valueOf(args[1]).doubleValue();
            System.out.println("The second number is: " + args[2]);

            double d2 = Double.valueOf(args[2]).doubleValue();
            System.out.println("The sum is: " + addServerIntf.add(d1, d2));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае исключение `java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host`
 может возникать по причине не запущенного реестра RMI на серверной машине.

### Решение

---

**Запустите RMI реестр используя команду:** `start rmiregistry`.

Проверим без использование данной команды:

[image]

---

Запускаем сервер:

[image]

---

Теперь проверяем с использованием команды `start rmiregistry`:

[image]

---

Перезапускаем успешно сервер:

[image]